# How to remove object from array in loop after some time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to remove(Destroy) my gameobjects(hurdles) from the loop that are random generated after some time by random.range but it is not removing. I tried to change the " Destroy(newSelected[ran], 5)" position but not working.

```
         private void OnTriggerExit(Collider theCollision)
            {

              if (theCollision.gameObject.tag == "Ob2")
               {
                a = theCollision.transform.position;
                x = a.z + 3f;
                x_ = a.z - 1f;
                startingpoint = a.x;

                for (int i = 8; i <= 64; i += 8)
                {

                    var ran = Random.Range(0, 4);
//selecting gameobjects(hurdles) by default.
                    print(ran);
                    b = new Vector3(startingpoint + i, 0.050f, Random.Range((int)x_, (int)x));
                    if (ran == 2)
                    {

                        newSelected[2]=Instantiate(gameObjects[2], new Vector3(startingpoint + i, 0.050f, a.z), Quaternion.identity);

                        print(x_);
                    }
                    else if (ran != 2)
                    {

                        newSelected[ran]=Instantiate(gameObjects[ran], b, Quaternion.identity);


                    }

                    Destroy(newSelected[ran], 5);
//I want to destroy my gameobjects(hurdles) here that are instantiate after some time.
            } 
      }
     } 
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? does it have any error?

Comment: Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);
UnityEngine.Object:Destroy(Object)
my_player:OnTriggerExit(Collider) (at Assets/Scripts/my_player.cs:184)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above will attempt 7 times to destroy an object in the newSelected array at a **random** index of 0, 1, 2 or 3. Meaning that, for example, it might attempt to destroy the object at index 0 multiple times and therefore returning a null error after the object has been destroyed the first time.

To avoid that error you should check that newSelected[ran] is not null before attempting to destroy it.

**I would recommend you create a separate component to handle the random delay destroy functionality and add it to the GameObject you are instantiating.**

Here's a quick C# Script that will handle destroying the GameObject it is attached to:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyAfterRandomDelay : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Tooltip("Minimum delay value")]
    public float MinimumDelay = 0f;

    [Tooltip("Maximum delay value")]
    public float MaximumDelay = 4f;

    // keeps track of elapsed time
    private float _elapsedTime= 0;

    // Keeps track of random delay 
    private float _randomDelay;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Sets random delay on start
        _randomDelay = Random.Range(MinimumDelay, MaximumDelay);

        Debug.LogFormat("{0} will be destroyed in {1} seconds!", this.name, _randomDelay);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        // Increment time passed
        _elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        // Proceed only if the elapsed time is superior to the delay
        if(_elapsedTime < _randomDelay) return;

        Debug.LogFormat("Destroying {0} after {1} seconds! See Ya :)", this.name, _elapsedTime);

        // Destroy this GameObject!
        Destroy(this.gameObject);

    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you don't need a script attached to each object to do this. You could use the original script and array, and drop the important bits from this script into a loop in `Start()`

Comment: Thanks bro, but is their any other way to do this? i just want to remove my game objects after some amount of time.

Comment: @SaadAhmed that's exactly what the script I included does once it is attached to a GameObject :)

Comment: Thank you soo much Sir @JeromeMaurey-Delaunay, really appreciated. :) (y)